# SOLVED - DELETE row from Database and From table

Tags: java, mysql, crud, sql-delete, delete-row

i'm trying to delete data from database and from table.
I've make three files. One on this for connection to database and CRUD, one for windowbuilder and the last one for Contact information for db. But when run the software and try to delete row, i can delete row from table but not from database. Can someone help me please?
thanks !

Rubrica.java (windowbuilder)

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel) listaContatti.getModel();


if(listaContatti.getSelectedRowCount() == 1) {
dm.removeRow(listaContatti.getSelectedRow());
try {
RubricaBusiness.getInstance().eliminaContatto(listaContatti.getSelectedRow());
} catch (SQLException e1) {

e1.printStackTrace();
}

} else {
if(listaContatti.getSelectedRowCount() == 0) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Seleziona un elemento nella tabella.");
} else{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nessun elemento selezionato!");
}
}}
});
```

RubricaBusiness ( Connection and CRUD DB)

```
public void eliminaContatto(int id) throws SQLException {
String sql = "DELETE FROM contatti WHERE id=?";
PreparedStatement ps = getConnection().prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

ps.executeUpdate();
ps.setInt(1, id);

}
```

ERROR:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkAllParametersSet(PreparedStatement.java:2211)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2191)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2058)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
    at it.progetto.rubrica.business.RubricaBusiness.eliminaContatto(RubricaBusiness.java:67)
    at it.progetto.rubrica.view.Rubrica$6.actionPerformed(Rubrica.java:262)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

UPDATE FOR SQLEXEPTION (switch) thanks by user "mikeb":

```
ps.setInt(1, id);  
ps.executeUpdate();
```

UPDATE for delete data from Database:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel) listaContatti.getModel();
                int row = listaContatti.getSelectedRow();
                int id =(int) listaContatti.getValueAt(row, 0);
                dm.removeRow(row);
                    try {
                        RubricaBusiness.getInstance().eliminaContatto(id);
                    } catch (SQLException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: put the ps.setInt(1, id); before the execute

Comment: What do you mean delete from DB? - you can only delete data from tables. Example please.

Comment: i want to delete from database in base of row selection.

Comment: If this question is solved, please delete the solution material (so the question is still a question) and post a self-answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling stuff in the wrong order. You need to set the value for the statement before calling it. Switch:

```
ps.executeUpdate(); // Wrong, because you have not set the id for the statement yet
ps.setInt(1, id); // Useless, because you have already run the statement!
```

to

```
ps.setInt(1, id);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: ok. now there aren't errors. but don't delete data from database